# How do I call a python script on the command line like I would call a common shell command, such as cp?

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal

Suppose I've got a script I can run with:

```
python hello_world.py
>>> "Hello, world!"
```

How can I configure hello_world.py to be executable **without** `'python'` or `'./'`:

```
hello_world
>>> "Hello, word!"
```

EDIT: Thanks all for the suggestions! The shebang and path solution and the python package solution both worked. I checked the python package solution because I liked the added features of tacking the script onto my path via `pip install -e .` without hand-editing my path variable and catching the script during `pip freeze > requirement.txt` calls.

Comment: Ref. [shebang/hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)); then just make it executable and resolvable on the PATH.

Comment: Fun question, plus one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this for the first time a few hours ago. What you can do is turn your python script into a 'package', then install that package.

I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial) and it worked for me. If you follow it you will be able to type 'runner' on the cmd line and your script will run.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Linux or Unix, at the top your file, it's typically something like

```
#!/bin/python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

You'll need execution perms to run the file as well, in that manner. Use chmod

```
chmod +x hello_world.py
```

If you're not running as root, you may require sudo, and that would be

```
sudo chmod +x hello_world.py
```

And then attempt to run with

```
./hello_world.py
```

if you must dispense with the ./:

```
alias ./hello_world.py=hello_world
```

Comment: Aliases isn't very scalable. The other solution is to add it to a directory in your PATH, or update PATH to include your diretory.

Comment: @tdelaney: +1. The standard thing to do is to combine that with the `chmod` step: `install -m755 spam.py ~/bin` or `sudo install -m755 spam.py /usr/local/bin`. (Although sometimes the even better thing to do is create a `distutils` setup script and then `pip install .`…)

Comment: There is a decent chance that 'sudo' is not enabled. Otherwise, I like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to use aliases, i.e. `alias hello_world='python hello_world.py'`

This will of course only work in the folder where hello_world.py lives, but `alias hello_world='python full/path/to/hello_world.py'` would work anywhere.

This will only work for your bash session, but adding the alias command to your ~/.bashrc will make it permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Make the script executable (using chmod +x hello_world.py)
- Rename it to hello_world
- Move it to a directory that is in your PATH (e.g /usr/bin)

Answer (score 1):

1. If the ~/bin directory is not there, create it and move the python script to this  directory.
2. Rename `hello_world.py` to just `hello_world`
3. At the beginning of the script, add

   ```
       #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```
4. then

   ```
       chmod +x hello_world
   ```

**Note:** If you are creating the **~/bin** directory in **Ubuntu**, *logout* and *login* again (to run the ~/**.profile** file). The default ~/.profile will automatically add the ~/bin directory to your path.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to fix up the `export PATH=` stuff in ~/.bashrc . FWIW, I prefer to make a symbolic link to ~/bin rather than moving the script from my main python directory.

Comment: I have added a **Note** for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It only needs to be readable for "python hello_world.py" to work.
You can chmod +x hello_world.py to make it executable. 
Append '.' to your PATH environment variable if you need the "./"

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be install the script using setup.py and configure entrypoints like this.

entry_points={'console_scripts':  ['hello_world = hello_world:main']},

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `python` script in your PATH (or add it to your own PATH).

I'm assuming you don't have a `$HOME/bin`, if you do skip this -

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
```

next, create `$HOME/bin/hello_world`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Hello, World!"
```

then,

```
chmod +x $HOME/bin/hello_world
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Then you can,

```
$ hello_world
Hello, World!
```